# How to connect to use two internet connections on Mikrotik Router?

Tags: internet

I have two internet links coming to my Mikrotik router. I want to push the certain type of traffic from one internet line and rest from the other.
for e.g. I have the broadband line from which I wish to push the youtube and shopping website traffic whereas the rest of the traffic should go through the other internet leased line link.

What possible configuration should be done in the Mikrotik router to do this? (It is load balancing but of a different type)

Comment: Is this incoming traffic? Do you have two different public IP addresses? It sounds like Policy Based Routing, and a quick Internet search turns up a bunch of hits, including the Mikrotik Wiki.

Comment: Yes. I have incoming traffic from two different internet connections with different public IPs. I've looked at the policy based routing wiki also but wasn't able to do that perfectly. Just out of curiosity, will this hamper the smoothness of internet?

Answer (score 1):

You should act like this:

1. Create a Mangle rules that mark all Youtube packets with a RoutingMark
2. Create a static route for this traffic on the right gateway. (Be sure to select the right RoutingMark).

Check [this link](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Policy_Base_Routing)